# Multiple conditions for db_update

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal 7 simple updates work like this:

```
$num_updated = db_update('joke')
->fields(array(
'punchline' => 'Take my wife please!',
))
->condition('nid', 3, '>=')
->execute();
```

But what if I have multiple conditions( say nid >=3 and uid >=2). Writing something like:

```
$num_updated = db_update('joke')
->fields(array(
'punchline' => 'Take my wife please!',
))
->condition('nid', 3, '>=')
->condition('uid', 2, '>=')
->execute();
```

does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/310086

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have written will do the equivalent of:

```
'...WHERE (NID >= 3 AND UID >= 2)"
```

If you wanted an OR conditional you need to nest the statements as such (no, it's not very intuitive):

```
->condition(db_or()->condition('NID'', 3, '>=')->condition('UID', 2, '>='))
```

There is also db_and() [default for chaining multiple condition methods] and db_xor() that you can use when nesting.